# Is the span of Eigenvectors equal to the span of the column space of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

1. I wanted to know if the span of eigenvectors is related to the span of the matrix itself. (Ex: equal to the column span of the matrix?)
2. Is there a way to represent the columns of a matrix in terms of its eigenvectors and eigenvalues?
3. Lastly, how the second point is related to finding the powers of the matrix

Comment: This is pretty much all explained by any section on diagonalization in any linear algebra textbook.

Comment: 1. Consider the two spans for the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.

Comment: I am currently reading the Introduction to linear algebra by gilbert strang. I am getting confused by the explanation in the book and wanted to look for a more intuitive explanation if any.

Comment: The eigen vectors for the given matrix is equal to [0,0] & [0,0]. I am not getting the point

Comment: Those aren't the eigenvectors (the zero vector is never an eigenvector by definition). The eigenvectors for that matrix are $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and that's it. This is a "defective" case where the eigenvectors don't span the space. The other way that the two spans can fail to coincide is if the matrix is singular (i.e. not invertible). In the singular case there are often (not always) eigenvectors that aren't in the column space. An example for that "not always" is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ which is both defective and singular.

Answer (score 1):

For $1$: yes, there is a relation, but it isn't always a nice one. Sometimes, the matrix is *defective*: it doesn't have enough eigenvectors to span the space. However, you can **always** express a matrix in terms of [generalised eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) via something called [Jordan Normal/Canonical Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). The nice relation is when the matrix is diagonalisable - see below - if it is instead defective, it has a non-diagonal Jordan form.

For $2)$: it depends. If your matrix is *diagonalisable*, then yes. What does that mean? It means that it has a diagonal representation, right, but importantly for this question that really means: if you change your basis into your eigenvectors, that **there are enough linearly independent eigenvectors to span your space**.

Examples:

> $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$This is Andreas' example. This matrix is *not* diagonalisable. It has "two" eigenvalues ($1$, with multiplicity $2$), but the only eigenvectors are multiples of $(1,0)^T$. $2D$ space cannot be spanned by a single eigenvector, so the best you can do is leave this in its Jordan Normal Form - which it is already in!

> $$\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}$$This is diagonalisable. Its eigenvalues are $5,-1$, with representative eigenvectors $(1,1)^T,(1,-1)^T$. Notice that these are $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors, which is sufficient to span $2D$ space. Let's first build this matrix of eigenvectors: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ And I also want to find its inverse, so that we can go from the normal basis to this one: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$Now I need to think about the diagonal form: when acting on the eigenvectors, by definition this matrix will just scale them by the eigenvalues. Therefore I can write a diagonal matrix with $5,-1$ on the respective entries. Altogether now: $$\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}=\underset{P}{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}}\underset{D}{\begin{pmatrix}5&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}}\underset{P^{-1}}{\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}}$$This works because every vector in $\Bbb R^2$ can be expressed in terms of the eigenvectors of this matrix, because there were two different ones, and the matrix on the right converts a vector in terms of $\bf i, j$ into one in terms of the eigenvectors; the diagonal part scales the eigenvectors as it normally would, and the last matrix converts everything back into vectors in terms of $\bf i,j$.

What about powers?

For $3)$, consider this: when the matrix is diagonalisable, I can express it in terms of $PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix and $P$ is the change of basis to the eigenbasis (linearly independent eigenvectors). Remember I can only do this *sometimes*. But suppose now is such a time, and I can write $A=PDP^{-1}$. Let's think about integer powers:

$$A^2=(PDP^{-1})^2=PD\color{red}{P^{-1}P}DP^{-1}=PD\color{red}{I}DP^{-1}=PDDP^{-1}=PD^2P^{-1}\\A^3=A^2A=PD^2P^{-1}PDP^{-1}=PD^2\color{red}{P^{-1}P}DP^{-1}=PD^2DP^{-1}=PD^3P^{-1}$$

A straightforward exercise in induction reveals that, for any natural number $n$:

$$A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$$

Why do we care? Well, $D^n$ is *really easy* to calculate. You just raise the diagonal entries to the relevant power. Then it's a lot easier:

Example:

> $$\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}^n&=PD^nP^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5^n&0\\0&(-1)^n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\\&=\cdots\\&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^n+5^n&(-1)^{n+1}+5^n\\(-1)^{n+1}+5^n&(-1)^n+5^n\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$

And a difficult problem becomes easier. Actually, since that matrix was symmetric, it wouldn't have been too hard to inductively find its powers, but this technique is very powerful and fairly general - it fails when the matrix is *defective*, because it won't have the nice diagonal form.

Comment: For the first question, I am still wondering if there is a direct link between the column span of the matrix and the span of the eigenvectors. Thanks for the explanation for the 2nd and 3d parts

Comment: There is the link. When there are enough linearly independent eigenvectors to span all of the space, the span is the same. When there aren't enough linearly independent eigenvectors, the span of the matrix is determined by the Jordan Normal Form: it is the span of the eigenvectors + any generalised eigenvectors. If none of the eigenvalues are zero, the span of the columns is always all of space; if an eigenvalue is zero, then the span is all of space **minus** the span of that eigenvectors + its generalised eigenvectors which appear in the JNF. @ssuraj

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Powers of the JNF can be found analytically also. It's more complicated than the diagonal setting but still possible (and the solution is well documented).